# Can Opereto be installed on any cloud-native environment?

Tags: automation, automated-tests, integration-testing, devops, system-testing

I saw that Opereto can be installed on a single node using docker-compose. However, I would like to scale by installing Opereto on Kubernetes. Is it supported as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Opereto is now released in two delivery methods: docker-compose for a small footprint single node installation and Kubernetes cluster. 
https://docs.opereto.com/installation-get-started/

You can install Opereto on any environment that supports Kubernetes vanilla. There might be some differences in the deployment commands if you use OC command instead of kubectl but it should be straight forward to work it out.

Please note, however, that Opereto requires an HTTPs ingress to be configured. Ingress configuration may be different from one K8s provided to another.